# PDF form to feed into database and produce reports

Tags: database, forms, pdf, report

I would like to create a program or an application whereby a new user is sent a **PDF** form to fill out. Once they have filled out the form they should be able to click submit and the data should be saved into a central database and used to produce various reports (eg. mobile phone list, contracts pulling relevant fields into aa prepared template). When submit is clicked it should also send a notification to pre authorized users including a 'signed' version of the filled out pdf as an attachment.

I have been away from computing world for so long and so much has changed - could anyone advise what language/combination of languages would best suit this type of application?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: How do you plan on users accessing your app? For example, do they download your application and run it, or do they use your app through a browser?

Comment: Ideally I would just send them an email with the pdf form attached which they would be able to fill out, 'sign' and submit. At a later stage it could include functionality for it to be sent to a line manager for approval before the data is ingested into the database...but for now if it could just send the data straight to a database

Comment: It appears Adobe Acrobat, most likely only pro, has a features for creating forms on PDF, distributing PDFs with email, and creating PDFs that allow users to submit with http to a server. How you do this, I don't know but that might be a start. I also imagine there is some tool out there that does this for free. This is [the link](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/form-submit-e-mail-demystified) I base this on.